# Universal Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, enums

I am new in WPF, and I try to implement a dialog view with one Combobox (ComboboxView) that loads Enumerations and Lists. I show data in a Datagrid and when I click on a cell depending on the type of the cell (an Enum cell or a 'list' cell), I call this ComboboxView and I load the Enum items or the whole list and I set the current selected value. The property ItemsSource of the combobox has a binding with ViewModel property Sources. It can be a list of EnumItem or List

How can I implement one view that loads Enums and List in the same way?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code. What you have tried so far?

Comment: A list of enums is still a list `Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().ToList()`